# How can I stop replication in owl carousel slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I'm working on owl carousel slider & I `have to set max 5 items in a time`. This is working fine when this is `5 items` & `more than 5 items` but when there is `less than 5 items` then items repeating, how can I fixed it.

When there is less than 5 items then it should not be repeat.

My Code:-

```js
$(function(){

$(".recent-visited-slider.owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    items: 5,
  });
  
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<div class="recent-visited-slider owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div class="item">item 1</div>
<div class="item">item 2</div>
<div>
```

ThankYou for your efforts!

Comment: You delacred items: 5, you need to increase the <div class="item"> more than 5. Becasue there is only 2 divs

Comment: @Aman Sharma yes this is the problem, actually <div class="item"> dynamic, sometime it can be less than 5 so that time <div class="item"> should not be repeat.

Comment: At this condition use loop:false

Comment: @Aman Sharma thank you so much this is working fine now...